# Php выборка с групировкой под заголовок. Как?

Tags: php, sql

Подскажите как правильно мне реализовать выборку.
Есть массив сотрудников и к каждому присвоена группа в БД "f" под номером отдела

```
<?
$sql_result = $db->query( "SELECT * FROM `localuser` WHERE f !=0 ORDER BY f + 0 "  );
while ( $row = $db->get_row( $sql_result ) ) {
$name=  $row['name'];
$f= $row['f'];
echo '
<div class="cbp-item '.$f.'">
<span><b>'.$name.'</b></span>
</div>
 ';
}
?>
```

По итогу выходит html код:

```
<div class="cbp-item 1">
<span><b>Имя сотрудника в группе 1</b></span>
</div>
<div class="cbp-item 2">
<span><b>Имя сотрудника в группе 2</b></span>
</div>
<div class="cbp-item 2">
<span><b>Имя сотрудника в группе 2</b></span>
</div>
<div class="cbp-item 3">
<span><b>Имя сотрудника в группе 3</b></span>
</div>
<div class="cbp-item 4">
<span><b>Имя сотрудника в группе 4</b></span>
</div>    
<div class="cbp-item 4">
<span><b>Имя сотрудника в группе 4</b></span>
</div>
```

Подскажите как сделать, что бы была перед каждой группой был заголовок например:

```
<h1>Группа 1</h1>
    <div class="cbp-item 1">
    <span><b>Имя сотрудника в группе 1</b></span>
    </div>
<h1>Группа 2</h1>
    <div class="cbp-item 2">
    <span><b>Имя сотрудника в группе 2</b></span>
    </div>
    <div class="cbp-item 2">
    <span><b>Имя сотрудника в группе 2</b></span>
    </div>
<h1>Группа 3</h1>
    <div class="cbp-item 3">
    <span><b>Имя сотрудника в группе 3</b></span>
    </div>
<h1>Группа 4</h1>
    <div class="cbp-item 4">
    <span><b>Имя сотрудника в группе 4</b></span>
    </div>    
    <div class="cbp-item 4">
    <span><b>Имя сотрудника в группе 4</b></span>
    </div>
```

На данный момент я вижу только возможность задать WHERE f=1, потом копировать код и задать в WHERE уже f=2 и так далее. Но мне кажется это совершенно не правильно. Ведь на данный момент 10 отделов, и получиться 10 одинаковых по своей сути кусков кода.
Спасибо.

Comment: обычно проще отделить обработку данных и их вывод, сначала вытащить, сгруппировать (в случае с PDO это просто), а потом уже вывести двойным циклом.  А применительно данного фрагмента кода, ставите изначальное имя группы в null, если и смотрите. если отличается от текущей строки, то выводите новое название и заменяете значение текущего.

Comment: на уровне php получить полный список сотрудников как есть. Потом пересобрать получившийся массив в новый, сгруппировав по группе. Третьим шагом будет вывести всё, используя 2 цикла (один по группам, другой по сотрудникам, который будет вложенный)